# Activate Cron job from a PHP page

Tags: php, cron

I googled but didn't found any solution

```
I have a PHP page that takes 45 minutes to execute.
```

What I am trying to achieve is:
1. Whenever I run a URL abc.com/test.php the script should check the cron job and activate it (run myscript.php) .
2. And should execute the page until it's complete.

So the PHP should call a cron job and execute it `ONLY` once when it is requested.Is Cron right approach

```
I do not want the script below, which i tried This will add a script that runs every day at 9:30am.

    exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n30 9 * * * /path/to/script" | crontab -');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why set a new cronjob, if you only want to execute it once?

```
exec('php -f /path/to/script >> /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

This will run the script. Echo all the output into the nowhere and use fork, so it will run in the background and your Request won't wait for a return.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!